# How to specify numbered sections in Pandoc's front matter?

Tags: yaml, pandoc

I would like to specify numbered sections via Pandoc's support for YAML front matter. I know that the flag for the command-line usage is `--number-sections`, but something like

```
---
title: Test
number-sections: true
---
```

doesn't produce the desired result. I know that I am close because you can do this with the geometry package (e.g. `geometry: margin=2cm`). **I wish there was a definitive guide on how Pandoc YAML front matter handling.** For example, the following is very useful (avoids templates), but its discoverability is low:

```
 header-includes: 
 - \usepackage{some latex package}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In order to turn on numbered-sections in latex output you need to use `numbersections` in your YAML block. If you ever want to "discover" things like this with pandoc just poke around the templates:

```
 $ grep -i number default.latex
 $if(numbersections)$
 $ grep -i number default.html*
 $
```

As you can see this option does not work with html.

Markdown and YAML I tested with:

```
 ---
 title: Test
 numbersections: true
 ---


 # blah

 Text is here.

 ## Double Blah

 Twice the text is here
```

If you need it to work with more than beamer,latex,context,opendoc you will need to file a bug at github.

Comment: Great tip about poking around in the default templates. I don't know why secnumdepth is getting ignored for me when I do `pandoc -f markdown -S -s --standalone --toc -Vnumbersections -Vsecnumdepth=4 -t latex` but thankfully secnumdepth is manipulable in the template file.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat, try `pandoc -f markdown -S -s --standalone --toc -numbersections -Vsecnumdepth=4 -t latex`

Comment: @chus, according to [pandoc documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html), to show section number in pdf output, the correct options in command line is `--number-sections` or simply `-N`.

Comment: @jdhao, you are right. Thank you for correcting the options.

Comment: Does `number_sections` also work? I see different examples of this variable across the internet, and it's weirdly missing from https://docs.zettlr.com/en/core/yaml-frontmatter/#frontmatter-variables.

Answer (score 16):

In order to show section number in the produced output pdf, there are two choices.

#### In YAML front matter

Add the following setting to begin of markdown file

```
---
numbersections: true
---
```

#### In command line

We can also use the command option to generate pdf with numbered section. According to [Pandoc documentation](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html), the correct options is `--number-sections` or simply `-N`,

```
pandoc test.md -o test.pdf --number-sections
# pandoc test.md -o test.pdf -N
```