# Automatic numbering of generated ToC in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid, kramdown

I'm using [Kramdown's ToC generation](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/converter/html.html#toc) in Jekyll and am wondering I can make it somehow support automatic numbering, so that this markdown:

```
## Header A

### Subheader

## Header B
```

Gets turned into this HTML:

```
<h2>1 Header A</h2>
<h3>1.1 Subheader</h3>
<h2>2 Header B</h2>
```

Apparently this could be done in [CSS](http://philarcher.org/diary/2013/headingnumbers/) or JavaScript, but I'm looking for a Markdown->HTML only solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pay attention to this part in kramdown documentation:

> All attributes applied to the original list will also be applied to
>   the generated TOC list and it will get an ID of markdown-toc if no ID
>   was set.

So, simply replace

```
- This list will contain the toc (it doesn't matter what you write here)
{:toc}
```

with

```
1. This list will contain the toc (it doesn't matter what you write here)
{:toc}
```

to get numbered ToC instead of unnumbered.

Comment: This will only apply to the ToC, not on the headers itself. Is there a way to apply auto numbering to headers as the TS is asking?

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [kramdown config](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/converter/html.html) no way to get this natively.
The plugin way can solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/A4Vision/enumerate-markdown

```
pip install enumerate-markdown
markdown-enum filename.md <minimal level> filenameoutput.md
```

Minimal level can be 1,2,3 etc depending on which header level you like to assign #1 to.

The github mentions no minimal level option as required, but in my case it only worked providing a level.

Example - input

```
# header 1
text
## header 2
text
# header 3
text
```

Output

```
# 1.  header 1
text
## 1.1  header 2
text
# 2.  header 3
text
```

As stated in [Are numbered headings in Markdown / Rdiscount possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19999696/are-numbered-headings-in-markdown-rdiscount-possible/51033038#comment120492702_51033038)

As headers are now numbered, they will be numbered in TOC and in your headers.